# "Position measurement diode" identification

Tags: identification, photodiode

We have a component laying around our lab that we have been using to take some measurements.  Supposedly it reads the position (x/y coordinates) of a laser beam (standard 5 mW red laser pointer) on the central black area.  It has worked well enough for us so far, but we would like to use it to test some flight hardware, so we need a datasheet that will give us figures for linearity and bandwith.  Here is what we know about it:

- `TP7` is a -15 V supply, `TP5` is a +15 V supply, and `TP6` is ground.
- Outputs are `TP1`-`TP4`.  Two of them output positive and negative intensity, the other two output x and y position.  We seem to get better linearity by dividing the x/y channels by the intensity channel.
- The two chips are [quad opamps](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa131.pdf).

[image: Nikon D3300 + DX AF-S Micro-NIKKOR 40mm 2.8G]
[image: Nikon D3300 + DX AF-S Micro-NIKKOR 40mm 2.8G]
[image: BB ® 13ZCWX5 OPA4131NJ]

The board is about 1 1/8" by 1 5/8".

Here is what we would like to know about it:

- Bandwith (not so important, just needs to be above ~1 kHz)
- Linearity (very important, we need 1% or better)
- What do `TP8` and `TP9` do?  Why did whoever set this up leave these unconnected?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would take some pretty heavy duty reverse engineering to answer all of those questions.

Comment: @Matt We think this is some type of evaluation board, and the script we use to read data references a datasheet (but not which one), so I think that one exists.  My intent was for this to be more of a research question (not a reverse-engineering question), hoping that someone would recognize the manufacturer.

Comment: @2012rcampion Link to the script?

Comment: I would wager it's fairly old since the op amps are still marked with the Burr-Brown logo.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany The script just reads in voltages from the four pins on a LabJack U3.  The relevant bit is a comment where it divides the inputs, saying `# datasheet says pos = diff/sum`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have an evaluation board from [First Sensor.](http://www.first-sensor.com/en/products/modules/evaluation-modules)

There are links to the chips and information about the eval boards at that link.  Yours most resembles the [DL100-7](http://www.first-sensor.com/sites/www.first-sensor.com/files/downloads/datasheets/optical_sensors/modules/evaluation_modules/evaluation_boards/dl100-7-pcba3-500744_0.pdf).  The DL100-7 has 1% accuracy.

The layout of the eval boards is very similar, but not identical.  I think you may have an older version of the board.
If TP8 and TP9 are disconnected, then your module isn't wired like the current eval boards.

Maybe you can ask for info on old boards (or find them in an archive on the site) or maybe you should just purchase a new device with known characteristics  - it is also entirely possible that First Sensor is a competitor of the company that built your module.

A quick look around doesn't find any one else building PSD eval boards in that form factor, though, so it ought to be First Sensor.

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of similar manufacturers (Hammamatsu, First Sensor, [Laser Components](http://www.lasercomponents.com/fileadmin/user_upload/home/Datasheets/sitek/2l20_su9.pdf)). The CLI markings may be the PCB maker not the manufacturer.

Here's a contemporary board from [First Sensor](http://www.first-sensor.com/sites/www.first-sensor.com/files/downloads/datasheets/optical_sensors/modules/evaluation_modules/evaluation_boards/dl100-7-pcba3-500744_0.pdf):

[image]

Your requirements of 1% linearity and >>1kHz BW seem to be normal for PSD sensors.